# How to prevent fractional values in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview, floating-point

my goal is to show a messagebox that tells the user that they can't input fractional numbers if they try to input a floating point number in my datagridviewcell. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx

Comment: What is the data store behind the grid?  Is it a DataTable object?  If so, then I recommend that the DataColumn in question has the appropriate data type.  An Integer in this case.  That way the user is prevented from the incorrect data entry in the first place.

Comment: The data behind it is stored in a dataset from an excel file